# How to save params to xml file in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have SomeController

and have @xyz object

```
@xyz = XYZ.new(params[:xyz])
```

and I have to save all fields from form to xml file.

So what are the steps.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following should work

```
@xyz = XYZ.new(params[:xyz])
xml_string = @xyz.to_xml
File.open("some_file_name.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(xml_string) }
```